# Is the Halo 4 GOTY edition DLC on the disc or an included code?

Tags: halo-4

Is the Game of the Year edition's included downloadable content downloaded from the disc or included as single-use codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a DLC [code](http://youtu.be/fXzR_mOOPrM?t=2m40s) included in the box with the other DLC and Avatar Items. I found the link on youtube and contains an unboxing of the Halo 4 GOTY Edition.